# Arithmetic encoding - probaility

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I'm trying to understand how AC works. The thing that bugs me the most is how is probability chosen or calculated. In the given example message `abcde` produced the following result:

```
Symbol | Probability | Range  
---------------------------------  
a      |     30%     | 0.00, 0.30  
b      |     15%     | 0.30, 0.45   
c      |     25%     | 0.45, 0.70  
d      |     10%     | 0.70, 0.80  
e      |     20%     | 0.80, 1.00
```

How come `a` has probability of `30%` and `d` only `10%` is this chosen completely at random ? What if message was longer an included say another `d` would the probability for `d` be greater than ?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the probability is not a part of arithmetic encoding. This is the task of the probability model. 'More likely' messages have a more efficient encoding.

If the examples, the probabilities are likely picked at random (or picked to make a good example).